# How to animate Marker from coordinate A to B in Google Maps iOS (Swift) in a particular duration

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I want to animate Marker on GoogleMaps for iOS
between 2 points in at a particular speed or duration
like point A and B are two points and I want to move marker from A to B
then how to do it if I want to do in  a particular time frame like suppose 3 seconds then it automatically takes 3 seconds to move from Coordinate A to B.

I want to make effect somewhat like Uber have when cars are moving from one point to another.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter** like,

```
func showFirstMarker()
{
  // Fetch the coordinates of first location and plot as marker.

  // Call a function after 3 seconds, to show the second marker.

  DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 3, execute: {self.showSecondMarker()})

}

func showSecondMarker()
{
   // Erase all markers in maps.

   // Fetch the second coordinate and plot as marker.
}
```